# как переобразавать один интерфейс(или обект) в другой интерфейс

Tags: typescript

есть интерфейс

```
interface IName {
  'name-a': string;
  'name-b': string;
  'name-c': string;
}
```

или обект

```
const name = {
  'name-a': 'a',
  'name-b': 'b',
  'name-c': 'c',
};
```

нужно получить на его основе такой интерфейс

```
interface IRoot {
  name: string;
}
```

нужно автаматически все это получить

типо `IRoot<typeof name>` либо `IRoot<IName>` и на выход получить то что на верху

суть в том что IName будет разростатся и он на основе css modules, то есть типы автаматически выводятся из того что в стилях.

руками писать 'name' не вариант

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Непонятно какая связь первого и последнего?

Comment: @AlexeyTen связ в корне, все свойства имеют(либо будут иметь) обший корень

Comment: С картинкой стало ещё непонятнее. В ней вообще-то нет общего префикса.
Ну и чем вас не устраивает выведенный тип?

Comment: @AlexeyTen из картинки (`font-family`, `font-size`, `font-weight` корни) там еще есть, не перечислить же все)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подозреваю что вам нужно это https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

```typescript
interface IRoot {
  [k: `name-${string}`]: string;
}

// ok
q['name-ok'] = 'ok';
// error
q['name-error'] = false;
q['error'] = 'string';
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=23#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4ChnINoDWAXMgAYhwC2EAtACQYDOYUoA5gL6kC6JzrINgG4sHLFgA2EMMgCOJdAF5MHEVll4A5BWo0A9gU3dkyzQc1qN2qrWhQ9UIyeTwJjCCKt2HT0-3YWQA)

А может проще определить generic-тип:

```typescript
type IRoot<prefix extends string> = Record<`${prefix}-${string}`, string>;

let q: IRoot<'name'> = {};

// ok
q['name-ok'] = 'ok';
// errors
q['name-error'] = false;
q['error'] = 'string';
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgSgewcAPGAThAZgSwB5QR7AQB2AJgM5SXDo6kDmAfFALxRwQDGC65KAAYASAN4Zs%20AL4BaMbXpMpggDQ06DFgG4AUDoA2EYFACOALliJkKAOSkAhgFsIN1h1FTdOgPTeoCAGsdEwBtOycIGUCbAF12KBto3V9CdHQ%20SmCwh2cZCDS%20WPise31KCF1Qm3z09CKOGwVNG10gA)

Comment: не совсем, вместо name может быть age, мне бы трансформатор каторый бы работал с любыми ключами автаматически

Comment: Т.е. вам нужно выделить общую часть ключей интерфейса? Нуу, наверное это тоже можно сделать, но выглядит каким-то сильным переусложнением и плохой архитектурой…

Comment: не с архитектурой у меня проблем не было даже в жудких проектах, просто вилосепед у меня типо tailwind, и есть проблема с дефолтными классами, проблему решил вот только еще типизацию на это прикрутить и было бы топ.

Comment: @Armen обновил ответ

Comment: обновил вопрос, надюсь чуть понятнее вышло.

Comment: добавил картинку, шя должно быть вообще все понятно.